# How to identify if a google place details result is a state (administrative_area_level_1)

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Currently we are using Google places api’s address_components array to identify if searched place is a state or country. For state and country place we are passing state code and country code on search submit. Following are the scenarios we are using to identify place detail result type:

**State scenario:** address_components has 2 items with administrative_area_level_1 type in 1st item and country type in 2nd item.

```
  "address_components" : [
     {
        "long_name" : "California",
        "short_name" : "CA",
        "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
     },
     {
        "long_name" : "United States",
        "short_name" : "US",
        "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
     }
  ],
```

**Country Scenario:** address_components has 1 item and its types has country

```
  "address_components" : [
     {
        "long_name" : "United States",
        "short_name" : "US",
        "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
     }
  ],
```

If address_components item list has more than 2 items then the selected place is not considered as state or country. While few searches like "Oaxaca" or "New York" are returning more than two items in address_components array.

**Oaxaca:**

```
  "address_components" : [
     {
        "long_name" : "Oaxaca",
        "short_name" : "Oaxaca",
        "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
     },
     {
        "long_name" : "Oaxaca",
        "short_name" : "Oaxaca",
        "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
     },
     {
        "long_name" : "Oaxaca",
        "short_name" : "Oax.",
        "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
     },
     {
        "long_name" : "Mexico",
        "short_name" : "MX",
        "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
     }
  ]
```

**New York**

```
  "address_components" : [
     {
        "long_name" : "New York",
        "short_name" : "New York",
        "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
     },
     {
        "long_name" : "New York",
        "short_name" : "NY",
        "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
     },
     {
        "long_name" : "United States",
        "short_name" : "US",
        "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
     }
  ]
```

Is there any other way to identify if a search place detail result (like Oaxaca) 
is a state (administrative_area_level_1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can use the types field that is returned along with address_components field

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#PlaceDetailsResults

> types[] contains an array of feature types describing the given result.

In case of country,

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJCzYy5IS16lQRQrfeQ5K5Oxw&key=YOUR_API_KEY

you will see something like

```
{
  "html_attributions":[

  ],
  "result":{
      "address_components":[
      {
        "long_name":"United States",
        "short_name":"US",
        "types":[
          "country","political"
        ]
      }
      ],
      ... 
      "types":[
         "country","political"
      ],
      ...
  },
  "status":"OK"
}
```

In case of state something like

```
{
    "html_attributions":[

    ],
    "result":{
        "address_components":[
        {
            "long_name":"Nebraska",
            "short_name":"NE",
            "types":[
               "administrative_area_level_1","political"
            ]
         },
         {
            "long_name":"United States",
            "short_name":"US",
            "types":[
               "country","political"
             ]
         }
         ],
         ...
         "types":[
             "administrative_area_level_1","political","point_of_interest","establishment"
          ],
          ...
      },
      "status":"OK"
}
```

And city will have something like

```
{
    "html_attributions":[

    ],
    "result":{
        "address_components":[
        {
            "long_name":"Oaxaca",
            "short_name":"Oaxaca",
            "types":[
               "locality","political"
            ]
         },
         {
            "long_name":"Oaxaca",
            "short_name":"Oaxaca",
            "types":[
                "administrative_area_level_2","political"
             ]
          },
          {
              "long_name":"Oaxaca",
              "short_name":"Oax.",
              "types":[
                 "administrative_area_level_1","political"
              ]
           },
           {
              "long_name":"Mexico",
              "short_name":"MX",
              "types":[
                 "country","political"
              ]
            }
            ],
            ...
            "types":[
                "locality","political"
            ],
            ... 
        },
        "status":"OK"
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: So if address components has more than 2 items, we should not consider it as a state.

Comment: You have a `types` field for the result and this field says what type has the result. I don't understand why you need to analyze number of items in address components if you can know the type of the result immediately from the `types` field.